# WordPress: First login of a new browser session always fails

Tags: wordpress, authentication, cookies

I'm working on a WordPress website: https://samarazakaz.ru/

The client discovered a strange bug. After newly opening a browser the first login always fails, second one succeeds.

I tracked down the issue to a strange cookie with the name `RCPC` that is being set when the login form is submitted. If the cookie is missing then the login fails regardless of proper credentials.

I searched high and wide for any information about this cookie but could not find anything useful. The only thing remotely resembling my case was on some discussion on a site called https://codeforces.com/ . But nothing on that mentioned anything related to WordPress.

The site has a bare-bones setup with Elementor and my own plugin. And nothing in my code messes with cookies or the login process. I downloaded all website files and search in all files for "RCPC" but found nothing.

The site is behind an Nginx proxy, but I could not find any connection with this cookie and Nginx either.

I noticed that the value of this cookie is constant. So, as a workaround I jerry-rigged my plugin to set this cookie any time when it's not set. But, of course, I'm not very happy with that solution because I don't know if this will just stop working one day.

**Update:**

I verified that this is coming from the hosting. I renamed the `/wp-login.php` file and made a request to it, and it didn't return a `404` error but a `200` page with the same redirect code and the header to set the cookie. The hosting is reg.ru .

As far as I can figure this is a counter measure against automated password guessing. Any request (POST, GET, etc) to the `/wp-login.php` will get the redirect script with the cookie setting header. Only requests containing the correct `RCPC` cookie will get forwarded.

Upon further testing found that the value of the `RCPC` cookie is some kind of hash generated from the request's IP address. Because all of our computers got the same one but from other locations its different.

This does not cause any problem if the standard WordPress login form is used because that lives at the `/wp-login.php` address, so the first GET request will generate the cookie. However, we had a custom login page which didn't access `/wp-login.php` until the form was submitted.

Based on these discoveries I made a workaround, which is simply adding a one line JS script to the login page which makes a (fetch) request to the `/wp-login.php` page and simply discards the result. This is enough to set the cookie in the browser so that the form will work at the first try.

Comment: Any caching plugins installed?

Comment: @AlexKnopp : No. Only 3 plugins are active & present: Elementor, Elementor Pro & my own plugin for custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Need on hosting disable test-cookie-module